GitHub GraphQL, tokens and SPA
I'm working on a new revision of my portfolio, and this project will have a new feature, it will list all my pinned GitHub projects with the GraphQL API.
Following the documentation https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/guides/forming-calls-with-graphql, I created a new token like said in doc:

All fine-grained personal access tokens include read access to public repositories. To access public repositories with a personal access token (classic), select the "public_repo" scope.

Find the code here: https://gist.github.com/abenevaut/4b706f7947cdbb666e2de11fd2d69381
My question is, how is it OK/secure to transpile this token in js that will expose it publicly ?
